# Let x be a point in $ \overline A $ then prove that x is either a interior point or a boundary point of A.

Tags: real-analysis

Here $ \overline A $ is defined as intersection of all closed sets containing A. Then $ \overline A $ is the smallest closed set containing A.I chose a point which is neither interior nor boundary point of A then x doesn't belong to A and there exists an $ \epsilon $ > 0 such that (x-$ \epsilon $,x+$ \epsilon $) $ \cap $ A is empty.But I cannot understand how does that imply x doesn't belong to $ \overline A $ and I have to use  the above definition of $ \overline A $.

```
     Please give me hint.
```

Comment: Look at the complement of $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$.

Comment: The complement of (x-$ \epsilon $,x+$ \epsilon $) is a closed set containing A and so $ \overline A $ is a subset of complement of epsilon neighbourhood of x so x does not belong to $ \overline A $. Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the complement of the open set $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is closed and contains $A$ as a subset.

Then this complement also contains $\overline A$.

Further: $$\overline A\subseteq(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)^{\complement}\iff\overline A\cap(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)=\varnothing$$

Comment: Yes I got it from david sir's hint still thank you